# Can't read the JSON response I send to android application

Tags: java, android, json

Hello I am trying to create a local database on my android device. I made the php script that returns the following response:

> {"ruta":[{"id_ruta":"1","ime_rute":"1","duljina_rute":"6","max_visina":"3","trajanje_rute":"5","opis_rute":"2","lokacija_rute":"4","oprema_rute":""},{"id_ruta":"2","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"3","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"4","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"5","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"6","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"7","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"8","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"9","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"10","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"11","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"12","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"13","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"14","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"15","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"16","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"17","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"18","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"19","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"20","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"21","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"22","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"23","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"24","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"},{"id_ruta":"25","ime_rute":"test","duljina_rute":"0.02","max_visina":"184.51","trajanje_rute":"00:00:42","opis_rute":"hop","lokacija_rute":"hop","oprema_rute":"hop"}],"success":1}

And when I try to just write the contents of the response in LogCat it says that there is no value. Here is a part of my code that I use.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray rute = null;

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

private static final String TAG_RUTA = "ruta";
private static final String TAG_ID_RUTA = "id_ruta";
private static final String TAG_IME_RUTE = "ime_rute";
private static final String TAG_DULJINA_RUTE = "duljina_rute";
private static final String TAG_MAX_VISINA = "max_visina";
private static final String TAG_TRAJANJE_RUTE = "trajanje_rute";
private static final String TAG_OPIS_RUTE = "opis_rute";
private static final String TAG_LOKACIJA_RUTE = "lokacija_rute";
private static final String TAG_OPREMA_RUTE = "oprema_rute";


List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

// HERE I GET THE JSON RESPONSE
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(link,"GET", params);

try {
    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    //AND HERE I TRY WRITING STUFF FROM THE RESPONSE

    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

    new Delete().from(Ruta.class).execute();

    Log.d("RUTE GET INT",String.valueOf(json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS)));
    Log.d("RUTE GET JSON STRING",json.getString(TAG_RUTA));
    if (success == 1) {  

    rute = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RUTA);
    Log.d("RUTE",rute.toString());
    for(int i = 0; i<rute.length(); i++){
         JSONObject r = rute.getJSONObject(i);

         Ruta nova_ruta = new Ruta();

         nova_ruta.IDRute = Integer.parseInt(r.getString(TAG_ID_RUTA));
         nova_ruta.Naziv = r.getString(TAG_IME_RUTE);
         nova_ruta.Udaljenost = Integer.parseInt(r.getString(TAG_DULJINA_RUTE));
         nova_ruta.MaxVisina = Integer.parseInt(r.getString(TAG_MAX_VISINA));
         nova_ruta.Trajanje = r.getString(TAG_TRAJANJE_RUTE);
         nova_ruta.Opis = r.getString(TAG_OPIS_RUTE);
         nova_ruta.Lokacija = r.getString(TAG_LOKACIJA_RUTE);
         nova_ruta.Oprema = r.getString(TAG_OPREMA_RUTE);

         nova_ruta.save();
                        }
```

Here is the LogCat [image: screenshot]

Comment: and just a hint: you might want to use the android Volley library for JSON. Implementing the `onErrorResponse(VolleyError)` callback lets you easily debug errors by checking the error type with `instanceof`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the value of key `ruta` is an *array*, not a *string* as you requested for. The line

```
Log.d("RUTE GET JSON STRING",json.getString(TAG_RUTA));
```

leads to the exception.